# Can't persist a OneToMany relationsship with Hibernate

Tags: jpa, ejb

I have the following entity class **Kunde** which has a OneToMany relationship to **Verlauf**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "_id", name = "_id_verlauf")
private List<Verlauf> verlauf = new ArrayList<Verlauf>();
```

I trie to persist some Verlauf but i got the error 
**Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails**

This is how i do the persistens:

```
  @EJB
  private KundeLadenLocal kunden;

    private void fuegeZahlZuKundenKontoHinzu() {
    try {


        Kunden k = loginBean.getAktuellerKunde();

        Verlauf verlauf = new Verlauf();
        verlauf.set_id_kunde(k.get_id());
        verlauf.setDatumDerAbfrage(new Date());
        verlauf.setSuchbegriff(suchfeld);

        kunden.VerlaufAnlegen(verlauf);

        k.getVerlauf().add(verlauf);

        kunden.kundeUpdate(k);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The session Bean:

```
@Override
public void VerlaufAnlegen(Verlauf verlauf) {
    em.persist(verlauf);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see you complete entity code, but what i see let me think that you are using jpa relationships in the wrong way. Try to change you entity code in way I posted below. One more improvement think about to use [entity graphs](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/) instad of eager loading on entity level, and read something about java code conventions.

```java
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Kunde {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "kunde") // property name in your bean Verlauf
    private List<Verlauf> verlauf;
}



import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

@Entity
public class Verlauf {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "kunde_id") // column name in your database table used for Verlauf entity
    private Kunde kunde;
}
```

than you can pass `Kunde` object direct to `Verlauf` ojbect:

```
verlauf.setKunde(kunde);
```